# Cancel loading of video in webview [ in the middle] does not work

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

webView.stopLoading doesnot work while loading youtube video.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{

            WebView webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.sssWebView);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            WebSettings webSettings = webReview.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
            webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
            webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
            webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

            webview.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID);

}

@Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
        if(progreesDialogue!=null && progreesDialogue.isShowing())
        {

            progreesDialogue.dismiss();


        }


        webview.clearView();        
        webview.stopLoading();       
        this.finish();        
        super.onBackPressed();

        }
```

Comment: You should use `android-webview` instead of `webview`... and similar for `android-activity`, `android-intent`, etc. :)

Comment: What do u mean? I am using     <code>   import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient; </code>

Comment: I mean the stackoverflow tags